# Error message in wso2 dss

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 esb4.7.0 and wso2 dss 3.1.0.I have created a dataservice in dss and tested using try this service tool.It's working fine but when same dataservice is being fetch in esb using it's adress endpoint it showing following error -

**ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.statistics.internal.ResponseTimeCalculator} -  wso2statistics.request.received.time is null in the IN MessageContext**

why so?is their any problem with esb?or it's internal problem?please let me know..

Comment: U have to describe it more. Do you want to invoke the dataservice from your proxy service (ie ESB) and this is the time that you encounter this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set message headers using Header mediator. At least you have to set "To" and "Action" headers before you send payload to the data service. To get the write value of To and Action headers you can use Soap Tracer tool in monitor tab of WSO2-DSS management console. Run the tool, try the data service and refresh the tool to see the results of your trying. In the left side of the page of Soap Tracer tool you will see the To and Action, copy values from there and put them in header mediators you are using.